# PYTHON Numpy where time condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

I have the following target: I need to compare two date columns in the same table and create a 3rd column based on the result of the comparison. I do not know how to compare dates in a np.where statement.

This is my current code:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now() #set the date to compare
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=7) #set delta
time_delta = now+delta #now+7 days
```

And here is the np.where statement:

```
DB['s_date'] = np.where((DB['Start Date']<=time_delta | DB['Start Date'] = (None,"")),DB['Start Date'],RW['date'])
```

There is an OR condition to take into account the possibility that Start Date column might be empty

Comment: Try changing `|` to `or`

Comment: STill not working. I get the following: "cannot compare a dtyped [datetime64[ns]] array with a scalar of type [bool]"

Comment: `(DB['Start Date']<=time_delta | DB['Start Date'] = (None,""))` should probably be `(DB['Start Date']<=time_delta | DB['Start Date'].isnull() | DB['Start Date'] == "")`.

Comment: ALso, when dealing with null values in pandas DataFrames or Series, just use `np.nan` or `pd.Series.isnull` or `pd.DataFrame.isnull` for comparisons.

Comment: What exactly is `DB`?

Comment: Also, what is `RW`?

Answer (score 0):

Would lambda apply work for you Filippo? It looks at a series row-wise, then applies a function of your choice to every value of the row. Whatever is returned in the function will fill up the series with the values it returns.

```
def compare(date):
    if date <= time_delta or date == None:
        #return something
    else:
        #return something else
DB['s_date'] = DB.apply(lambda x: compare(x))
```

EDIT: This will work as well (thanks  EyuelDK)

```
DB['s_date'] = DB.apply(compare)
```

Comment: You can simplify a little by using `DB['s_date'] = DB.apply(compare)` instead

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the insights. I updated (and adjusted for my purposes) the code as following and it works:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now() #set the date to compare
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=7) #set delta
time_delta = now+delta #now+7 days

DB['Start'] = np.where(((DB['Start Date']<=time_delta) | (DB['Start Date'].isnull()) | (DB['Start Date'] == "")),DB['Start'],DB['Start Date'])
```

They key was to add () in each condition separated by |. Otherwise was giving an error by comparing two different data types.